# tailwind form not positioning properly as fixed element

Tags: css, angular, tailwind-css

I'm using tailwind css to style a little angular app, the problem is:
i want my form to have a fixed position at the bottom of the page but it seems that classes like "top-100 left-50" are not working

home-component.html

```
<main class="container bg-green-200 h-full m-auto">
<app-search class="fixed top-100"></app-search>
  <app-fruits-cards></app-fruits-cards>
</main>
```

searchbar-component.html:

```
<form *ngIf="searchForm" [formGroup]="searchForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" class="bg-slate-100 rounded p-3">
    <label for="searchInput">Search</label>
    <input formControlName="fruitName" type="text" id="searchInput" class=""/>
    <button type="submit" class="rounded-full">search</button>
</form>
```

I actually tried to use the "top-100" class into the form element directly but it still doesn't work, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

There is no default defined class `top-100` the most near to it is `top-96` but you can define your default in tailwind.config file or use custom value like `top-[100px]`

Read about:
Adding arbitrary values here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-arbitrary-values

Defining classes in the config file here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration

Answer (score 0):

Try adding position relative to the container

Also i'm not sure about `top-100` ...

check here what values are allowed with the classes of top ..

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/top-right-bottom-left